# Using @autoreleasepool and sending autorelease message

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning objective-c and would like to clarify a thing:
when I use autoreleasepool should I send an autorelease message after using test object?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        TestClass* tc1 = [[TestClass alloc] init];
        //....... do some stuff with tc1
        [tc1 autorelease];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I use autoreleasepool should I send an autorelease message after using test object

They don't have *any* correlation whatsoever.

What you should do depends on what you want to do and whether or not you're using automatic reference counting.

If you're using ARC (which I think is not the case, since you send an `autorelease` message), then you don't have to worry about releasing objects at all in simple cases. (If you have to use advanced memory management with more complicated models, then ARC is even more complex than MRC, but anyway...)

If you're not using ARC, there are two options. `autorelease` lets an object be released at the end of the innermost-scoped autorelease pool. So in the example you provided, it's OK to do this.

However, autoreleasing is primarily intended to dispose of ownership when returning objects from a method/function, and in general, you want to explicitly send a `release` message to an allocated-initialized object when you no longer need it.

Comment: ok. So if I use ARC I shouldn't do autorelease even though I return an object form method?

Comment: @amplifier try it out! If you use ARC, the compiler will kick you in the bottom for using `autorelease` and won't compile your code.

Comment: @amplifier (hint: because the autorelease, once again, is done automagically - [see this.](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/))